# undefined reference to studAverage

Tags: c++

I am facing a problem on reference in C++,
I am about to calculate the average of class marks,
Now I am stuck with the error.
my class in filename classAverage.h is

```
#ifndef CLASSAVERAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASSAVERAGE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class studAverage {
public:
void test();
void sDetails();
double avgMarks(vector<double> testMarks);
//  void getStudentWithLowMarks(vector<string> names , vector<double> marks);
// void getStudentWithHighMarks(vector<string> names , vector<double> marks);

private:
string sName;
double sAvg;
double cAvg;
double totalMarks;
};

#endif
```

My class implementation code in classAverageimpl.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classAverage.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void studAverage :: test(){
cou<<"::"<<endl;
}

void studAverage :: sDetails(){
// sName = name;
//sAvg =  testMarks;
cout<<"gggg"<<endl;
cout<<"enter the list"<<endl;
}

double studAverage :: avgMarks(vector<double> testMarks){
int sum=0;
double classAvg;
for(int i=0;i<testMarks.size();i++){
    sum+=testMarks[i];
}
classAvg = (sum/testMarks.size())*100;
cout<<"The ave ::"<<classAvg;
return classAvg;
}
```

My main program in main.cpp is

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include "classAverage.h"
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 studAverage stud;
int sCount,i;
string name;
double marks;
vector<double> sMarks;
sMarks.clear();
vector<string> sName(10);
sName.clear();
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
cout<<"Enter num of students in the class"<<endl;
cin>>sCount;
for(i=0;i<sCount;i++){
    cout<<"Enter student details"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter student marks"<<endl;
    cin>>marks;
    sName.push_back(name);
    sMarks.push_back(marks);
}
cout<<"The size of name vector is "<<sName.size()<<endl;
cout<<"The size of marks vector is "<<sMarks.size()<<endl;
stud.sDetails();

return 0;
}
```

please help me out

Comment: Did you link your compilation unit (`classAverageimpl.cpp`) to your program?

Comment: In classAverageimpl.cpp  you have a typo: `#inclede "classAverage.h"` This might be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at the logic, just what made it not compile and there are several minor errors. Fix these and the program will run. Whether it will work as intended is a different question.

In classAverageImpl.cpp add:

```
#include <vector>
```

and change

```
#inclede "classAverage.h"
```

to

```
#include "classAverage.h"
```

Also `double studAverage::avgMarks(vector<double> testMarks)` needs to have a return value like:

```
return classAvg;    // add this at the end of the method
```

In main.cpp add:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Hi jpw i corrected all the changes u told but still i am getting the error like undefined reference to `studAverage::avgMarks(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)'|

Comment: @user1903535 After doing the changes I described the program did compile and run when I tried it. I can't say why it isn't working for you.

Comment: i included my changed code pls once go through...

Comment: @user1903535 Apart from a typo in `void studAverage :: test()` where you have a `cou` instead of `cout` this code compiles and runs fine for me, using MS Visual C++

Comment: actually i am using codeblocks is there any thing need to do in that.

Comment: @user1903535 I can't say. I tried compiling it directly using GCC/MinGW using the commandline `g++ -o test.exe *.cpp` and it worked too so I'd say the source is ok and maybe your Code::Blocks setup isn't. Try compiling the code from a command prompt instead.

Comment: Hi jpw, it is working for me when i pasted the code from classAvarageImpl.cpp to classverage.h. i think there is mapping problem in classAverageImpl.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#inclede "classAverage.h"` to `#include "classAverage.h"` in your `classAverageimpl.cpp'.

**EDIT::**

---

**A.** The `undefined reference to studAverage` is coming because your `#inclede` should be `#include`

**B.** On compiling `main.cpp` alone, you will get `Error C2679` because your `main.cpp` doesn't includes the `#include <string>`

**C.** On compiling `classAverageimpl.cpp`, you will get `Error C2065` and `Error C4716` because your `classAverageimpl.cpp` doesn't includes the `#include <vector>` and the method `double studAverage :: avgMarks(vector<double> testMarks)` expects a `return value of type double`

Comment: Hi, i changed it  still same problem

Comment: i am getting ths error "undefined reference to `studAverage::avgMarks(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)"

Comment: @user1903535 Perhaps create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (do read the link) to recreate the problem, then edit your question to include that instead of the other code. At the moment people can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: now i added the changed code, i am fighting with this problem from morning :(